# Тыквенное масло дорогое(-), однако-с, (-)предорогое

Tags: дефис

Как правильно?

> Тыквенное масло дорогое-, однако-с, -предорогое.

> Тыквенное масло дорогое, однако-с, предорогое.

Comment: Если вы словом _однако-с_ разделяете слово _дорогое-предорогое_, то дефисы нужны. Что тут может быть спорного, что вы вопрос аж задали? Вы слишком много вопросов задали сегодня.